# 12.04, how to switch gnome-fallback to use metacity permanently?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, compiz, metacity, compositing

I upgraded to 12.04 recently and found that my VNC connection wouldn't update, specifically when I connected it would display the desktop as it was, but would not update further.

I found disabling compositing by doing metacity --replace fixes this, however this does not "stick" and needs to be done every time I reboot the machine, how can I make this permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer doesn't tell me what gnome-fallback has to do with anything, please specify.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I am using gnome because I couldn't get vnc to work on unity at all on the previous version.

Comment: When you start a new session by logging out, after you enter your password, but before you hit enter, click on the little cog next to your user name. You'll get a bunch of choices. Pick Unity 2D, or GNOME Classic (No effects) and then hit enter. The choice you make is sticky. Neither Unity 2D nor GNOME Classic (No effects) uses compiz. (If you don't see GNOME Classic (no effects), you could install `gnome tweak tool` which will bring that DE along.)

Answer (score 1):

Edit or check the specific  session file in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions.You could use gedit ( with root permissions) for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a "Gnome Classic (no effects)" session when logging in.
This is gnome-fallback preconfigured to use metacity.